# Is it possible to pass overloaded method to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

i am new to threading, i am trying to pass overloaded methods to std::thread like below example

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <thread>    

int do_calculation(int x)    
{    
   std::cout<<x;    
}    

float do_calculation(float x)    
{    
   std::cout<<x;    
}    

int main()    
{    
   std::thread t1(do_calculation,20);    
   std::thread t2(do_calculation,200.0f);    
   return 0;    
}
```

but the program is not compiling and throwing error that 
`no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)'
    std::thread t1(do_calculation,20);`

Is there a way to call overloaded methods in thread?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to cast the functions to resolve overloading:

```
std::thread t1(static_cast<int(*)(int)>(do_calculation),20);    
std::thread t2(static_cast<float(*)(float)>(do_calculation),200.0f);
```

Additionally, you need to either [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) or [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) your threads lest you risk a fun trip to `std::terminate`:

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1lCfETuL5LdIlsP6)

Comment: Unintuitive as it sounds, this is the correct technique for getting a pointer to one of a set of overloaded functions.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you may wrap the call in lambda

```
std::thread t1([](int e) {do_calculation(e);}, 20);
std::thread t2([]() { do_calculation(200.0f); });
```

Answer (score 7):

If you can use C++14 then as an alternative to casting you can wrap the function call in a lambda and use auto parameter type deduction.  This will allow overload resolution and type deduction to work for you

```
std::thread t1([](auto var){ do_calculation(var); },20);    
std::thread t2([](auto var){ do_calculation(var); },200.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define RETURNS( ... ) \
  noexcept(noexcept( __VA_ARGS__ )) \
  -> decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOAD_SET( ... ) \
  struct { \
    template<class...Ts> \
    auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const\
    RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ) )\
  }
```

now we can do:

```
static OVERLOAD_SET( do_calculation ) do_calculation_v;
```

and `do_calculation_v` is an object that represents the overload set of `do_calculation`.

```
int main() {    
  std::thread t1(do_calculation_v,20);    
  std::thread t2(do_calculation_v,200.0f);    
  return 0;    
}
```

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) we can do this with lambdas and not require a named object:

```
#define OVERLOAD_SET( ... ) \
  [](auto&&...args) RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )

int main() {    
  std::thread t1(OVERLOAD_SET(do_calculation),20);    
  std::thread t2(OVERLOAD_SET(do_calculation),200.0f);    
}
```

There is a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) proposal to let you do this a bit simpler without the macro:

```
int main() {    
  std::thread t1([](auto...args)=>do_calculation(decltype(args)(args)...),20);    
  std::thread t2([](auto...args)=>do_calculation(decltype(args)(args)...),200.0f);    
}
```

backing up to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), if we don't care about `noexcept` or return values or the like, we can just do this:

```
int main() {    
  std::thread t1([]{do_calculation(20);});    
  std::thread t1([]{do_calculation(200.f);});    
}
```

which deals with 90% of the cases involved.  If your values are not hard-coded and are cheap to copy, just capture them in the `[]` lambda capture list.