# Deducing function overload in a templated function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing my own std::async analogue (has to work back to Intel13/gcc 4.4 STL), and this works fine:

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
struct return_value {
    template <typename T>
    using decayed = typename std::decay<T>::type;
    using type    = typename std::result_of<decayed<Func>(decayed<Args>...)>::type;
};

template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
typename return_value<Func,Args...>::type async(Func &&func, Args&&... args) {
    return func(args...);
}

void run(int a, double b) { 
    printf("a: %i  b: %f\n", a, b);
}

int main() {
    async(run, 1, 3.14);
}
```

But if I add an overload for `run`:

```
void run() {
    printf("no args\n");
}
```

Then it can't properly resolve:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:27:23: error: no matching function for call to 'async(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, double)'
     async(run, 1, 3.14);
                       ^
<source>:14:43: note: candidate: 'template<class Func, class ... Args> typename return_value<Func, Args>::type async(Func&&, Args&& ...)'
 typename return_value<Func,Args...>::type async(Func &&func, Args&&... args) {
                                           ^~~~~
<source>:14:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:27:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Func'
     async(run, 1, 3.14);
                       ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

How can I take a function as a template parameter and properly deduce the overload given the arguments?

Comment: You could do like the standard does and require the caller to select the overload they want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966603/is-it-possible-to-pass-overloaded-method-to-stdthread

Comment: Yeah I'd like to infer it if at all possible though, seems like it should be possible to SFINAE it somehow.

Comment: Do you want to be able to take any function like object or can you limit this to function pointers or `std::function`?

Comment: I'd probably be OK if it was just function pointers

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't see a way to disambiguate overloads unless you know the return type. You could assume return type `void` most common and to this then: (I am simplifying your example for brevity)

```
template <class F, class... Args>
auto async(F f, Args... args)
{
    return f(args...);
}

template <class... Args>
auto async(void (*f)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    return f(args...);
}

void run();
void run(int, double);

auto test()
{
    async(run); // calls run();
    async(run, 1, 2.); // calls run(int, double);
}
```

This does seem kind of fishy and confusing to the user. Why does it work when the function passed returns `void` and it doesn't if it returns `int`? So I don't recommend it.

So really the only thing you could do is let it in the hands of the user to figure it out.

So some solutions for the caller of your function:

### The good (and ugly) old way: use cast to disambiguate the overload:

```
async(static_cast<int(*)(int, double)>(run), 1, 2.);
```

I personally don't like this approach at all. I don't like the verbosity of it and most of all I don't like that I have to be explicit about something that should really be implicit.

### The lambda way

```
async([] { return run(1, 2.); });
```

I like this. It's not half bad. Still a little bit verbose, but way way better than other alternatives.

### The macro way

Yes, macros, in C++. Without further ado, there it is (perfect forwarding omitted for brevity):

```
#define OVERLOAD(foo) [] (auto... args) { return foo(args...); }
```

```
async(OVERLOAD(run), 1, 2.);
```

I am not going to comment on this one. I leave each and every one of you to judge this macro.

Comment: I was trying to come up with an answer. It looks like clang++ and g++ agree that given a parameter `R (*)(A...)` of a function template, both `A` and `R` can be deduced if the function argument is a non-overloaded function, and either `A` or `R` but not both can be deduced if the function argument is an overload set not containing function templates. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Note the macro way requires C++14 generic lambdas, but the question is tagged c++11.

Comment: @aschepler correct. The OP still has the other options. And this would be useful to other people.

Comment: @aschepler if you pass a non-overloaded function then both `R` and `Args` are deduced from the function argument. If instead you pass an overload neither `R` neither `Args` are deductible from the function argument. However `Args` is deductible from the rest of the arguments.

Comment: Not what I found in my tests. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/706fe628dbc78012 .  (And I'd expect this example to be valid by [temp.deduct.call]/6: If `P` is a function, function pointer, or pointer to member function, and the argument is an overload set not containing function templates, trial argument deduction is attempted using each member of the set.)

Comment: Oh, I see. The "trial argument deduction" in that paragraph means an attempt to match with the one `P`, not the entire function template being called. That does explain the results of that example.

Comment: @aschepler I was referring when the parameter is `R(*)(Args...)`.